# Cannot open tablespace

Tags: mysql

Sometimes the MySQL 5.6 database is prevented from starting after system restart. The error message is:

> 2015-07-09 14:49:02 1740 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace database/abstract_stats_extractor_type uses space ID: 3 at filepath: .\database\abstract_stats_extractor_type.ibd. Cannot open tablespace mysql/slave_relay_log_info which uses space ID: 3 at filepath: .\mysql\slave_relay_log_info.ibd

Deleting the `*.idb` files from the MySQL data path resolves the problem and the database is starting. But I would like to know the reason for that behavior.